How to trigger a event to refresh Configuration of multiple .net apis
We have over 100+ .net API whose configuration are fetched from gitlab configuration. Whenever someone updates the configuration, we do sync mirror and restart the service.
We have a requirement where without restarting we want to implement something where by initiating a event we can update config for all/selected service. Something of a sort of observer Pattern but at service level. Any Ideas how this could be achieved by making minimum amount of code changes.
We have a common nuget package where we could do change that can be used by all 100+ APIs.
